# Is there a cleaner way to define mapping definitions in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, mapping

I have a mapping class that maps DTO objects to Entity models and vice versa. The associations are currently stored in dictionary and all associations are added to the dictionary at runtime - called by a static constructor which calls a function that performs a ton of adds to the dictionary! See where I'm going with this? Its not nice I know.

From my perspective I can't see how I can get around manually defining these associations somewhere, but is there a better way to define the associations and then just load them into the dictionary with a simple loop opposed to adding an extra _dictionary.Add(dtoType, modelType); in the constructor for every new association. Also, I would like to keep these association definitions within the program, not in an external text/xml file.

Comment: There are hundreds of solutions, it depends on your needs. For instance you could loop the types by reflection and specify the relation by an attribute. Or you rewrite the while thing that you don't need this kind of mapping information....

Comment: @StefanSteinegger How could you get around not needing the mapping information - if that is what you mean (in the last sentence)? I did think about attributes however, the DTO's don't know of the entities because they are in a seperate assembly, and I don't really want to couple the Entity Framework classes with the DTO's as I think that makes everything a little messy - what do you think? Thanks for the reply

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - just to add, my needs are basically just to know what DTO objects should be mapped with what entity objects. :)

Comment: What about a naming convention? `UserEntity` is always mapped to `UserDto` ...

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - that is a good suggestion, I will spend some time to consider all my options and the "bigger picture" then go from there as I really don't want to start implementing it one way and then discover it's not suitable! As soon as I implement a solution I will of course post about it! Do feel free to make any other suggestions (I will definitely be considering the naming convention method) - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tool can work for you:

http://automapper.org/

We use it to map dto properties to entity properties. It works by convention and by configuration.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but with Automapper you still have to define what DTO to map with what entity right? What I am looking for is a way to define these associations in a clean manor... as far as I am aware Automapper doesn't offer a solution for this does it? Thanks

Comment: No, you're right it doesn't risolve your main issue. It only avoids more work to configure the actual mappings.

Comment: In fact I do use Automapper for actually mapping the properties - a little part of me was hoping I had missed out a feature which would solve my issue, but thanks for the input anyway :)

Comment: you're welcome. What about marking the dto with an attribute in which you indicate the associated entity and loop through reflection?